# Problema con función mail de PHP

Tags: php, mail

estoy implementando el envío de un email cuando el usuario se registra en el sitio, para ello recupero y envió los datos del formulario mediante AJAX a una página que instancia al objeto el cual contiene todo el código para el envío del html. La clase efectúa el envió del correo correctamente, pero el retorno que hace es el código del mail.

El código de mi clase es el siguiente:

```
class MailingController
{
public $conexion;
public $nombre;
public $paterno;
public $materno;
public $email;
public $userName;

function __construct(){
    $this->conexion = ConexionController::conexion();
}

public function nuevoUsuario($coleccionDatos){
    $this->email = $coleccionDatos['email'];
    $this->userName = encripta($coleccionDatos['email'],Secret);
    $this->nombre = $coleccionDatos['nombre'];

    $titulo = "Confirmación de Cuenta - #YoCuidoDeTi";
    $cuerpo = "
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html lang='es'><html style='width:100%;font-family:lato, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0;'>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
          <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>
          <meta name='x-apple-disable-message-reformatting'>
          <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
          <meta content='telephone=no' name='format-detection'>
        </head>
        <body style='overflow-x: hidden;'>
          <table style='width: 100%; background-color: #F3F3F3; margin-top: 50px;'>
            <tr>
              <td style='width: 15%;'></td>
              <td style='width: 70%;'>
                <h1>#YoCuidoDeTi</h1>
              </td>
              <td style='width: 15%;'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style='width: 15%;'></td>
              <td style='width: 70%; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;'>
                <h3>Completa tu Cuenta</h3>
                <br>
                <h3>
                  <strong>Hola $this->nombre</strong>
                </h3>
                <p>
                  ¡El registro de tu usuario est&aacute; casi listo!, solo necesitas asignar tu contrase&ntilde;a para poder personalizar.
                </p>
                <br/>
                <a href='https://www.yocuidodeti.com.mx/testing/www/confirmAccount/index?4f5ds59bpu8Dlt5a6dsIS8=$this->userName' title='Asignar mi COntrase&ntilde;' style='background-color: #2199E8; display: block; width: 70%; margin-left: 15%; border-radius: 3px; height: 50px; line-height: 45px; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;'>ASIGNAR MI CONTRASE&Ntilde;A</a>
                <br/>
                <p>
                  Con tu correo electrónico podrás dar seguimiento a tus StickerPack, concluir personalizaciones y re imprimir cuando lo requieras.<br/>Mantente en contacto con nosotros.
                </p>
                <br/>
                <hr>
                <p style='color: #CACACA;'>Confirmando esta suscripción estoy dando de conformidad y aceptando la política de privacidad de #YoCuidoDeTi. Podras modificar tus datos o darte de baja en cualquier momento.</p>
                <br/>
                <br/>
              </td>
              <td style='width: 15%;'></td>
            </tr>
          </table>    
        </body>
        </html>";
    $cabeceras  = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= "From: #YoCuidoDeTi <no-reply@yocuidodeti.com.mx>"."\r\n";
    $statusMail = mail($this->email, $titulo, $cuerpo, $cabeceras);

    if ($statusMail) {
        return 200;
    } else {
        return 400;
    }
}
```

Alguna sugerencia del por que me regresa el código html del mail?, Ya he revisado en varias ocasiones el código para ver si no estaba concatenando sin darme cuenta, pero al momento no he encontrado el problema o bug que ocasiona esto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no era el PHP, era que estaba importando un archivo que no tenía que estar.

Comment: Podrías dar más detalles por favor. ¿Qué exactamente modificaste del código de la pregunta para que funcione?

Comment: Había un include "colado" que mostraba el cuerpo del mensaje, por lo que la solución fue solamente eliminarlo ya que no era requerido. El include no estaba en el código que puse originalmente.